# Sending different errors depending on url Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-rest-framework

I am working in Django and I have a situation where I have written a custom validator that lives in the model.py

This validator should return a validationError when the input is bad.

In the project I am working on, we are using Django Rest Framework for our API and the Django admin panel for our admin panel. They connect to the same DB

My problem is that when the request comes from the API I need to return a 'serializers.ValidationError' (which contains a status code of 400), but when the request comes from the admin panel I want to return a 'django.core.exceptions.ValidationError' which works on the admin panel. The exceptions.ValidationError does not display correctly in the API and the serializers.ValidationError causes the admin panel to break. Is there some way I can send the appropriate ValidationError to the appropriate place?

here is my validation function (it lives in the model)

```
 def validate_unique(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OrganizationBase, self).validate_unique(*args, **kwargs)
    qs = self.__class__._default_manager.filter(organization_type="MEMBER")
    if not self._state.adding and self.pk is not None:
        qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.pk)
    if qs.exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Only one organization with \'Organization Type\' of \'Member\' is allowed.") #api
        raise exceptions.ValidationError("Only one organization with \'Organization Type\' of \'Member\' is allowed.") #admin
```

Those two lines at the end are the two errors written together for illustration's sake, in this case only the #api one would run

Basically I want to send errorA when the request is coming from the admin panel and errorB when the request is coming from the API

Thank you

Comment: I don't get how the API and Django's admin are linked.also "The exceptions.ValidationError does not display correctly in the API" is too vague to be helpful.

Comment: They are not linked they just use the same DB. Basically I want to send errorA when the request is coming from the admin panel and errorB when the request is coming from the API

Answer (score 0):

For raising different error classes write different validators.

rest framework api:

You can use the `UniqueValidator` or a custom validation function. check link [1]

eg:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (....)

    def validate(self, data):
        # my validation code
        raise serializers.ValidationError(....)
        return data
```

admin panel:

for the admin panel you can use a custom form [2].

eg:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        # my validation code
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(....)
        return cleaned_data


class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
```

In both the serializer and form you can access the instance object if not none.

[1] http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquevalidator

[2] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form